# Profiles-2--user-edit-page

Tags: 7, theming

I made my custom `user-profile-edit.tpl.php` using

```
function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
{

$hooks['user_profile_form'] = array(
                                // Forms always take the form argument.
                                'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
                                'render element' => 'form',
                                'template' => 'templates/user-profile-edit',
                                );
return $hooks;
}
```

Now I want in `user-profile-edit.tpl.php` to render the account form (default Drupal form for users) and my profiles2 forms, from the forms i created without click the upper links.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

After creation template you need only implements form_alter and set this custom theme for whole form - `$form['#theme'] = 'user_profile_form'` and then you will be able to build form structure inside your template.

You can check diff module ( 'diff_node_revisions' theme ) as an example.